# How to send a "you haven't used your app in a while " push notification in React Native using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

Just wanted to know from a high level how I would accomplish this.

I thought that when a user opens the application, I will keep track of the last opened time in a Dynamo DB table.

Then I could have a background worker constantly check and see if anybody hasn't used their app in 3 or 4 days and then send a push notification, ie, "you haven't used your app in a while, why don't you open it up and do XYZ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a very high level, there are two possible ways:

1.) Local notifications (you don't need AWS for this):
You can schedule a local notification, every time the user opens up the app (or better - every time the user brings the app to foreground). It works like: User opens app -> cancel old scheduled notification if existing -> schedule new notification for "in 3 or 4 days" -> ready :-)
You can use something like this: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification (see section Sheduled Notifications).

2.) You could do it with remote notifications (https://aws.amazon.com/sns/): 
You can go the way you proposed. Then you have to store an entry in your db with the push notification token of the device and the last time the app was opened. Your worker then has to check and send the push message to the device using a service like SNS.

I would recommend 1.) over 2.) because you are independent from the users internet connection when getting the app opening info. In 2.) you can miss the opening info, when the user opens the app without internet connection. Also 2.) is more expensive then 1.) when you scale your app.

An advantage of 2.) would be, that you are more flexible when and what you send in your notification, since you can edit it on server side. 1.) would mean that it is coded in your app (at least until you build a synchronization mechanism for the variables) :-)